# Ocultar opções da tela se usuário não tiver permissão

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Estou com uma dificuldade em uma aplicação web que estou criando aqui, estou usando `spring security` para fazer o controle de acesso, sessão e login, com backend `java` com `restful` e frontend com `primefaces`. Gostaria de saber se te como **ocultar** as opções que o usuário não tem permissão para acessar.

Atualmente eu intercepto a url e se não tiver permissão eu chamo uma outra tela que avisa esse impedimento pedindo para que ele volte para a home. Queria que essas opções não aparecessem para ele.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar as tags facelets do namespace *security* do Spring para renderizar condicionalmente os componentes JSF (inclusive os do Primefaces), conforme a autorização do usuário corrente.

O namespace é *http://www.springframework.org/security/tags*. Digamos que ele esteja mapeado para *sec*, um exemplo de código seria este:

```
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="USUARIO_BACANA">
    declare aqui os componentes para o usuário bacana.
</sec:authorize>
```

Mais informações: http://keylesson.com/index.php/2015/06/18/spring-security-authorize-tag-example-1993/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a solução, obrigado a todos que ajudaram e me guiaram a solução

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915134/how-to-use-the-spring-security-facelets-tag-library-in-jsf

Seguindo a solução desse usuario tudo certo